# I want this python problem's output in a tuple format, but dont know how to format it?

Tags: python, lambda

My program is :

```
def question_fourth_solution(array_nums):
    odd_len = len(list(filter(lambda x: (x%2 != 0),array_nums)))
    even_len = len(list(filter(lambda x: (x%2 == 0),array_nums)))
    print(odd_len,even_len)
    return array_nums

question_fourth_solution([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

I want my output in tuple form like given below:
(5,3)

Comment: `return (odd_len, even_len)`?

Comment: `print((odd_len, even_len))`?

Answer (score 3):

You may simply return the two results using `return odd_len, even_len`, which automatically returns them as a tuple equivalent to `return (odd_len, even_len)`, and print the return value of the function:

```
def question_fourth_solution(array_nums):
    odd_len = len(list(filter(lambda x: (x % 2 != 0), array_nums)))
    even_len = len(list(filter(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0), array_nums)))
    return odd_len, even_len

print(question_fourth_solution([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

Outputs:

```
(5, 3)
```

Inside your function, if you wanted to print the result as a tuple, you could do this using:

```
print((odd_len, even_len))
```